# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' can't get it working

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I have some code to get the new products from a supplier. Well I just started the code. But now I get a `NoneType` on the following line: `voorraad = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_stoc'}).text`.

It is the same as the other classes so it should be working, right?

this is the full code:

```
# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
url = "https://www.erotischegroothandel.nl/nieuweproducten/"

# Connect to the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'po_blok'})

records = []
for result in results:
    titel = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_titl'}).text
    staat = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_nieu'}).text
    voorraad = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_stoc'}).text

    records.append((titel, staat, voorraad))

print(records)
```

This is the html were I get the info from:

```
<div class="po_blok">
            <a href="/aanmelden" class="po_blok_crea">Klant worden</a>
            <a href="/login.html" class="po_blok_logi">Al klant? Klik hier om in te loggen</a>
            <a href="/massage/massageolie-siliconen/nuru_play_body2body_massage_gel__4l_40589.html">
                <img src="https://cdn.edc.nl/250/NGR04000R.jpg" alt="productnaam">
                <span class="po_blok_nieu">Nieuw</span>
                <span class="po_blok_titl">Nuru Play Body2Body Massage Gel – 4L</span>
                <span class="po_blok_stoc">Voorradig</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: `for result in results` - so you will do this many times, looking inside many `<div class="po_blok">`s. Maybe some of them contain all these `<span>`s, and others do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that many of those elements are `None`. The error is for those elements, so we handle it ..

```
# import libraries
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
url = "https://www.erotischegroothandel.nl/nieuweproducten/"

# Connect to the website and return the html to the variable ‘page’
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'po_blok'})

records = []
for result in results:
    titel = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_titl'}).text
    staat = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_nieu'}).text
    voorraad = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_stoc'})
    if voorraad:
        records.append((titel, staat, voorraad.text))
    

for record in records:
    print(record)
```

Output:-

```
('Nuru Play Body2Body Massage Gel – 4L', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')
('Nuru Play Body2Body Massage Gel – 335 ml', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')
('Nuru Glow Body2Body Massage Gel – 335 ml', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')
('P-Trigasm Prostaat Vibrator met Roterende Kralen', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')
('Gaia Eco Vibrator - Roze', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')
('Gaia Eco Vibrator - Blauw', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')
('Zachte Gladde Anaal Dildo', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')  .etc
```

Comment: Hi Abhishek Rai

When i use your option, i get only one result back, this is the last item that it can find.

for result in results:
    titel = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_titl'}).text
    staat = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_nieu'}).text
    voorraad = result.find('span', {'class': 'po_blok_stoc'})
if voorraad:
    records.append((titel, staat, voorraad.text))


Gives as result:
('Sensuva Ultra Dik Glijmiddel Op Waterbasis - Naturel', 'Nieuw', 'Voorradig')

Comment: I have added the output..Are you getting a different output than mine?

Comment: Yea i get only one result. and that is the last item in the product list on the website.
I'm not getting all products as you shown.

Comment: @TimBronsgeest    Have posted the entire code..try it.

Comment: OMG i had not used `for record in records` Thank you so much for your help!